# Force all layouts to have a maximum area on very large screens

Tags: android

I have a pseudo-legacy Android app with hundreds of layouts that work nice up to 7-inch screens. However, I would like to run it on really large screens too (10 inches and up), but the system expands all the layouts to fill up the remaining space. I would really like to be able to define a maximum area for these large screens and simply have a black border that fills the remaining area.

What I want is apparently exactly as the behaviour on the [screen compatibility mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#compat-mode) that existed in really old Android devices:

> On Android versions 1.6 to 3.1 the system runs your application in a
>   "postage stamp" window. It emulates a 320dp x 480dp screen with a
>   black border that fills the remaining area of the screen.

However, what the system does nowadays is:

> On Android 3.2 and up the system draws the layout as it would on a
>   320dp x 480dp screen then scales it up to fill the screen.

I just don't want that scale up. Any ideas without having to edit every single layout for this? (and without having to provide a `res/layout-large/` version for every single layout, evindently).

Comment: I think 10" would be under `xlarge`.

Comment: I have never used compatibility mode and have no idea how that would work,  but you could try only providing one/root layout in `layout-xlarge`. Set a padding to the root `ViewGroup` and give it a black background. Android *should* pick up the rest of the layouts from adjacent folders.

Comment: Tnx for answering! But that approach would force me to edit every single layout in the project to make all of them children of that root layout. That would be my last choice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a bit more logic and work but you might do:

- Have your layouts contained in a parent layout/Custom View.
- Parent layout will be default to match the sizing you need based on screen density or width/height as needed
- Custom View will extend FrameLayout for instance and will look for a flag that will restrict the sizing to a center block on large screen devices or full screen on devices you wish to support.

Hope this helps.

====
Update: 
Override the SetContentView Function and add the logic there - to have a container that bounds the layout in a center square if screen size is large or go directly to call super with the code as normal.

Comment: Tnx for answering, but it doesn't help. Please read the last paragraph of the question. I already know how to make an Android app, but I am trying to avoid editing every single layout in this scenario, just in case there is a special little-known configuration.

Comment: My suggestion is not editing every layout - this is one option but another would be to change the code in the activity (in case you use fragments) to have a container bound according to screen size. 
You can also edit the setContentView function and add logic there to save multiple layouts edits...

Comment: Tnx and I give you the bounty for the effort! I suppose there is no straight solution provided by the framework, so the `setContentView` override approach is probably the one less painful (thank God there is a common custom parent class for  all activities in this really legacy app, tho...).

Answer (score 0):

I have not actually used it. But There are few things you can try:

**1. Declare a maximum aspect ratio**

You can define `android:resizeableActivity` **false** for an entire app, or specific activities. The behavior is little different for Android 7.1 (API level 25) or lower, AND Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher devices. For Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, you can define `android:MaxAspectRatio` in the Activity tag and for Android 7.1 and lower you can define `android.max_aspect` in the Application tag. By doing so, Your app will be letterboxed when it runs on a device with an aspect ratio greater than the one you specify.

**2. Declare a maximum screen size**

You can disable resizing beyond a certain width by specifying the largestWidthLimitDp attribute in the  manifest tag. Then, instead of resizing your layout, Android enables screen compatibility mode, which draws your layout as it would on the largest size your app supports, and then scale up all the pixels to fill the screen.

You can read more about [**Screen Distributions**](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution)

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Tnx for answering! However, I've already tried both options and the system always resizes the layouts (as stated in the texts from the official docs I included in my original question, specifically the second one: "[...] then it scales it up to fill the screen"). Both options can lead to a centered layout with black margins on the horizontal sides at best, but I am specifically asking for something quite different (a maximum size all surrounded with black borders).